# iPhone simulator's Quicktime crashes when accessed through Safari

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, quicktime

I have a web application that contains links to *.m3u8 videos. Clicking these links on a physical iPhone in Safari opens up Quicktime fine. But clicking the links on the iPhone simulator will crash the device. To debug this, I wrapped a native app around this web app and ran it in debug mode.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithString:@"http://www.site.com"];
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Error message when clicking the *.m3u8 link:

```
2011-04-17 17:53:13.132 Site[2072:207] setting movie path: 
http://77.67.108.150/213.254.245.221/4c3d075ec4592/514/stream.m3u8 
[Switching to process 2072] 
[Switching to process 2072] Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”. 
[Switching to process 2072]
```

I'm not sure of the exact video format that Youtube uses, but their web app does not crash on the iPhone simulator. What do I have to do to make my app work like Youtube's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the iOS 4.2 simulator with one of the recent XCode versions that come with iOS 4.3, then it is probably the simulator? Does the crash happen on device does it happen with the iOS 4.3 simulator?

Comment: I downloaded the IDE last week. The simulator runs iOS 4.3.

Comment: It works on a real device. I think the simulator does not support every codec, so it crashes.

Comment: I have the same issue, what is the solution ? shall we need reinstall some media player, or remove/clean them ?

Comment: Try on a device. Make sure u use the most recent version of Xcode. And  save any created movieplayer in an ivar so ARC won't kill it when it detaches from your thread.